# str.find return statement incorrect, though I don't know why

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

```
def find_first_occurrence(msg: str, string_to_find: str) -> int:
    return str.find(msg,string_to,find)
```

This is the problem and I am supposed to complete/create the return statement, although my return statement is wrong. I genuinely don't know what I'm doing wrong, but when I test it out it clearly is wrong. Seems like a simple problem but I've been stuck on it for hours!

Comment: You don't add types to function parameters...

Comment: Can I ask why you need a function `find_first_occurrence` when `msg.find(str_to_find)` works fine?

Comment: What do you expect and what are you receiving? It should work. Putting it into a function won't magically fix it.

Comment: https://gyazo.com/12c0269c3df11842f2929f7bee130dd6    that is what I'm supposed to get, although I'm not passing those 2 cases

Comment: Provide more information. -1 means str_to_find wasn't found in msg. What is your full code?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. A screenshot of one function is not sufficient code, and a screenshot of two columns of integers is not sufficient input/expected output/actual output

Comment: I've already been told that, and it does make sense, but I am lost as to how i'd  incorporate that into this code. And sorry, will do Kevin, new to all of this.

Comment: Incorporate it into what code? You've provided nothing useful for us to help you.

Comment: Treyten, that's all it asked for. The question did not provide anything else. It just said complete the function below according to the docstring description

Comment: Excuse my misunderstanding, view my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be what you're trying to do:

```
def find_first_occurrence(msg, string_to_find):
    # looks like it wants you to not care about case, as 'H' returns 8 on an 'h'
    string_to_find = string_to_find.lower();
    msg = msg.lower();

    return msg.find(string_to_find);

print find_first_occurrence("October holidays: Halloween and Thanksgiving", "H");
```

Edit per reply:

`str.find(val)` returns the position of val in str. It is case-sensitive, so in "Hello, hello", `str.find("h")` would return 7 and `str.find("H")` would return 0.

The problem suggests that it should not consider casing by giving you the line `>>> find_first_occurrence('October holidays: Halloween and Thanksgiving', 'H') 8`.

Typically, `'H'` would get position 18, since the H is capitol. But they said you should get position 8, which is lower-case, suggesting casing shouldn't matter.

By doing `string_to_find = string_to_find.lower();` and `msg = msg.lower();` you remove cases all-together, so it will find the first occurrence of the lower-case letter on an all lower-case string.

Comment: Thank you! Although could you explain how you got this, step by step? Sorry, just new to programming and want to learn to the best of my ability. How did you figure it wants you to not care about case?

Comment: Edited my answer.